# photo album for website

Tags: php, javascript, photo-gallery

I want to have a photo album on my website such as this:

http://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/B9S9wNChMFRz6IAL_0n6pA?select=ADeqFE2Tj2s7eM8WuQibbQ

I'm looking for something where the photo that is displayed is also highlighted as thumbnail below that so that users can select photos rather than having to click next.

Also, I want to be able to have multiple photo albums so each set of thumbnails is different. Perhaps something where the whole page doesn't have to reload, but just the photo itself and the highlighted thumbnail?

I've done some research but I'm unsure of which type is best ie- PHP, javascript, etc...

I only have experience in HTML, CSS, and basic javascript and limited PHP.

I'm hoping somebody can point me in the write direction as to what to look for.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Learn jQuery.
   http://www.jquery.com
2. Rejoice!

http://blueprintds.com/2009/01/20/top-14-jquery-photo-slideshow-gallery-plugins/ <-- take your pick.

Comment: I really like this one: 


http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-3.html

 But is there anyway to hyperlink from another page to a specific photo, or will it always start at the first image?

Comment: It should be really simple to install. Just some basic jQuery, maybe just some slight changes to example code. And some HTML in the provided format. Easy-peasy. As for part two, you'll have to look into that particular plugin. But the general rule of thumb with these things is "yes you can".

Answer (score 1):

The jquery cycle plugin is fantastic and super easy to set up:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

and specifically it has the ability to do auto-thumbnailing as navigation:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html

If you know CSS you can take it from there.

Comment: I also like the second example you gave, but is there anyway to hyperlink to specific images from another page, or will it always begin on the first image? Also, does this one allow me to add 'next' and 'back' buttons?

Comment: true, well you could use #anchors at the end of your urls. Then have javascript read the anchor value and skip to that image. and yes, you can use prev/next buttons (see the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

As I myself am not the best (but still trying to get better!) when it comes to the more UI related technologies (CSS, JS, HTML etc), I have found using popular libraries such as JQuery Tools to be quite helpful and very easy to use. I believe the widget below matches up with what you are looking to do, and it also comes with a tutorial and helpful customization examples:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/gallery.html

Best of all I think JQuery Tools and Flowplayer are open source, so that means once you get the widget working, you can also delve into the code to try to gain a better understanding and hopefully one day take your own crack at a similar solution.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry! I didn't see the other answers before posting. It must have taken me 8 minutes to find the widget I was looking for.